# run compiled Scala Files on Java Virtual Machine

Tags: scala, jvm

Is it possible to run scala files with Java Virtual Machine? I am trying a lot but nothing works. Can someone give me some help with command line? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What OS do you have, how did you install scala, what error messages do you have?

Comment: Add `scala_library.jar` (also, `scala_swing.jar` if you use Swing) to your classpath and it should work.  Don't forget to add the current directory `.` or you won't be able to see your own classes.

Answer (score 8):

Well, it depends on whether you are generating a JAR or class files, etc, but it is pretty simple: you run it like any Java program, but including the Scala library as a dependency.

```
java -cp .:/path/to/scala-library.jar MyApp
```

Comment: java -cp .:/lib/scala-library.jar HelloWorld -->What do i have to add if my scala library path is C:\lib\scala-library ?

Comment: Is it also possible to compile use javac on scala files?

Comment: @Domenico No, it isn't. Note that scalac doesn't _compile_ Java files, it just knows how to read them to understand what they are declaring.

Answer (score 4):

Scala runs on the JVM. It does not have a separate virtual machine. But it does have its own libraries, so you will need to have Scala installed wherever you're running it.

If it's compiled you will have a .class file, so you just type in

```
scala -cp myClassPath myPackage.myFileName
```

as you would with Java. You don't need the `-cp` option if you've navigated to your classes folder.

It is possible to run Scala classes using the `java` command - you can probably Google how to do it, but you would need to sort out all the correct imports and there's no reason not to just use `scala` as above.